# 'dfg throw' isn't a type.foundation/changenotifier.dart:125 in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-test, dart-null-safety

I got this issues suddenly while debugging on **Emulator**.

```
     'throw' isn't a type.foundation/changenotifier.dart:125 throw FlutterError( ^^^^^^^^ :
 Error: Expected ';' after this. ../…/foundation/changenotifier.dart:125 throw FlutterError( ^^^^^^^^^^^^ : Error:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had resolved the issues by upgrading to the ***latest*** ***Flutter SDK version 3.3.2***.

Actually in **Flutter SDK** ,If you find the file changenotifier.dart file. at this location `/Users/sumitjaiswal/Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation`

You will find this code .

```
static bool debugAssertNotDisposed(ChangeNotifier notifier) {
    assert(() {
      if (notifier._debugDisposed) {
        throw FlutterError(
          'A ${notifier.runtimeType} was used after being disposed.\n'
          'Once you have called dispose() on a ${notifier.runtimeType}, it '
          'can no longer be used.',
        );
      }
      return true;
    }());
    return true;
  }
```

This has changed from **dfg throw** to **throw**. **So,I had just upgrade to latest version of Flutter SDK 3.3.2**.